# Display user profile image with Twitter API - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am using the Twitter API with jQuery to display a Twitter stream on my website. I would like to display the profile image, the tweet text and the time. I have everything working except for the image. Here is my script:

```
        jQuery.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/twitterapi.json?count=3&include_entities=true&include_rts=1&callback=?', function(data){
            jQuery.each(data, function(index, item){
                jQuery('.twitter').append('<div class="tweet"><p>' + item.text.linkify() + '</p><p><strong>' + relative_time(item.created_at) + '</strong></p></div>');
            });

        });
```

I tried to add item.profile_image_url but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

profile_image_url variable in the user variable

```
item.user.profile_image_url
```